# Attempt to create a table bloc using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehw9z.png)
What I'm trying to do with this Table is to insert same bloc ( Columns MNO to PQR to STU ) by a command button using VBA ( which is called mise à jour des coûts ) what I'm noticing is the code I'm using works to insert it to PQR [First attempt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IZL5.png) But then things go wrong as when I try to insert it another time it pushes PQR original content and adds a new blank bloc which will affect the order of the table.
This is the code I'm using. [Code VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRKSt.png). I realize in my code I am using commands that will always apply only to the P:R area that's why it's pushing the content to the next columns, but I don't know how to make the commands apply only to the last columns so this won't happen. I'm really looking for your responses on the matter.

The code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Const CaptionRow    As Long = 14
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim Cl              As Long
Dim Chart1          As Chart

With Worksheets("Tableau des couts")
    Cl = Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Columns(Cl - 2).Resize(, 3).Copy
    Cells(1, Cl + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(CaptionRow + 1, Cl + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Cl + 2).End(xlUp))
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End With
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).Select
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).ClearContents
Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 3).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
Chart1.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Tableau des couts").Range(Cells(CaptionRow + 1, Cl + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Cl + 2).End(xlUp)).CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlColumns
Chart1.ChartType = xl3DLine
```

End Sub

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not as a picture, so that it can be copied and run.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have added the code Variatus ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. It copies the last 3 used columns and pastes a copy of the same in the next 3 columns on the same tab.

```
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 051 - 21 Jun 20
    
    ' ==========================================================
    '   It's imperative that the Const CaptionRow should identify the
    '   longest row, meaning the row that has used cells reaching
    '   the furthest to the right.
    '   The code below uses this row to determine the location of
    '   both the last 3 used columns and the next 3 blanks.
    ' ==========================================================
    
    Const CaptionRow    As Long = 3     ' adjust as required
    Dim Rng             As Range        ' newly created columns
    Dim Cl              As Long         ' last used column in CaptionRow
    
    With Worksheets("Tableau des couts")
        Cl = Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Columns(Cl - 2).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Cells(1, Cl + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        ' delete all constants in copied columns 1 and 2
        ' starting from the row below CaptionRow
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(CaptionRow + 1, Cl + 1), _
                        Cells(Rows.Count, Cl + 2).End(xlUp))
        On Error Resume Next
        Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Variatus, 
for some reason the code buggs in this line : `Columns(Cl - 2).Resize(, 3).Copy`
It shows this error : Run time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Yes. This would happen if the variable `Cl` has a value of less than 3, meaning the code thinks there are less than 3 columns to copy from. Step through the code with F8 and check the value of `Cl` before the error occurs. The reason for too low a reading for `Cl` could be that the measure is taken in the wrong row. Please see the comment in the code.

Comment: Indeed it shows Cl=1, to more precise before this line `Cl = Cells(CaptionRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` Cl = 0 after it compiles Cl = 1.

Comment: Perhaps we have to go back to square One. (1) My code takes the last 3 columns and replicates them to the right of their original position. Why would you try to run such a program if you don't have 3 columns to copy from? Does my code solve a problem you don't have? (2) The code knows how many columns you have by looking at the row you identify as `CaptionRow`. Did you identify that row in the macro correctly?

Comment: The thing is I am actually trying to copy the last 3 columns, we are on the same page when it comes to the problem, it's just I don't know why it doesn't function correctly for my case.

Comment: Simply, Nassim. `Cl` is the number of the last used column. If Cl=1 you only have one column. If you actually have more than 1 column in your sheet the measurement is read wrongly. How many columns do you have in the row whose number you assigned to the constant `CaptionRow`? From your picture I can't know which row I'm looking at. I thought it might be number 3, and that is what I assigned to the constant. If, in reality, it's another row, change the number assigned to `CaptionRow` in the code.

Comment: You're right! thank you very much, right now I really understood the essence of it, before it was kinda blurry, if you don't mind I have one more thing to ask about, in my code I intended to not copy all the data from the columns, but only the data from the third column which containls formulas, and the name from from the first row in the first 2 merged columns. just like this [Example](https://imgur.com/a/AtLZWoh) . I'm sorry if I really bugged you with my problem but you really have been a huge help thanks a lot.

Comment: I've added to the code in my answer. Deletion starts 1 row below the `CaptionRow` so as not to delete the captions themselves. You can modify that here: `Cells(CaptionRow + 1,`. The code excempts the 3rd column. Note that even in the first two columns formulas will not be deleted by this action. Excel identifies formulas by their leading = sign. So, if you want to preserve values change them into formulas. '123.44' is a Value and will be deleted. `=123.44` is a formula and will be preserved. You can do that to captions, too.

Comment: Thank you so much Variatus, you've answered my question and helped me understand so many things and for that I'll be forever grateful, just one more thing that  I can't figure it out is, I'd like for the third column first row ( the date cell ) to be inserted empty so I could fill it manually, because apparently it still copies the last date of the last bloc.

Comment: Well thanks to your instructions, I was able to do it myself. You're awesome

Comment: Great! Here's your next task. Fill that cell, which you already identified, with the date you calculate from the previous date, like `[That cell].Value = Cells(CaptionRow, Cl - 2).Value + 1`. Once you got Cells(CaptionRow, Cl - 2) correctly - I just guess here - Value + 1 will advance the date found there by one day.

Comment: Hello hello ! your task inspired me to try this code `Cells(CaptionRow - 2, Cl + 2).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")` which assigns the date to that particular cell when the button is clicked, the weird thing is, it seems the date doesn't insert, when I change the cell to `Cl + 1` however it gets inserted but I need it in `Cl + 2` as I told you, do you have any idea what's wrong? are my cell coordinates wrong?

Comment: I don't believe that your coordinates are wrong because you can see the result and already know how to change it. I suspect it's your macro's action that's interfering with your plan, like inserting the date first and then clearing the column in which it was inserted. Use F8 to step through the code line by line. I think you will find that the date is correctly inserted and then deleted. In that case insert it later in the code, after deletion has been done.

Comment: I did it ! I should keep this F8 thing in my mind you keep mentioning a lot and just now I realized its true potential it helped me fix my code, thank you so much looking forwards to my next task

Comment: I have modified the code with the latest updates that I added, my next task that I thought of to improve my code more, is a visual representation where I wanted to represent the evolution of cost over time and precisely over every update that's going to happen.
Is it a good idea to have this representation in the same command button or have it in a separate button? because I think if I kept it in the same code it'll plot the curve before I get the chance to insert data on the newest bloc
Will a loop be the right choice so I can travel through the table and plot each time the 2 values I need?

Comment: Hard to say. We have have reached the limits of what can be achieved in one thread. Howe about you put it a little more work and then ask another question? You are right to think about your work flow at this time.

Comment: Hey there Variatus, I hope you're doing well, I have tried to do it myself but there's something I can't figure out, could you take a look at my recent thread?